# What does the expression "shared drive on one of the servers that we’d put high scores on" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, attachment-ambiguity

Here is a sentence:

> I remember that we had this **shared drive on one of the servers that
> we’d put high scores on**.

It is not clear to me if the scores were put on the drive or the server. The speaker is one of the developers of the game Angry Birds.

Any suggestions or inputs?

Comment: Both. The drive was on one server, and it was shared by other servers, because there had to be only one copy of the high scores.

Comment: What was the sentence before that one? I bet it's not ambiguous when it isn't stripped of all context.

Comment: The last night I was on safari, I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is technically ambiguous since there may be other drives on the server. However if a drive is not shared it would not be accessible from other computers, so the high scores would have been put on the shared drive, which was part of the server.

Answer (score 1):

The server had a drive that was accessible from other computers too, i.e. shared drive. If my understanding is correct, then there is no difference between “on the drive” or “on the server”, since the server was sharing the drive.

Comment: I have have a shared drive attached to a server that doesn't have high scores on it... without more context we can guess the drive had the high scores, because that's the most likely scenario, but we can't be sure. Servers can have more than one shared drive.